# While configuring expect, found source tcl directories instead of its installation location

Tags: build, tcl, expect, configure

I am building `gcc` from source. I meant to run the tests, which requires `dejagnu`, `expect` and `tcl`.

I first `configure`d `tcl` (using `dir1` instead of the actual dir for brevity), with

```
$ cd dir1/unix
$ ./configure --prefix="$HOME/usr/local"
```

and built.
Then I `configure`d `expect` with

```
$ ./configure --prefix="$HOME/usr/local"
```

At that point, tcl was found in `dir1`, i.e.,

```
$ grep tcl config.log
configure:2650: result: found dir1/unix/tclConfig.sh
configure:2656: checking for existence of dir1/unix/tclConfig.sh
configure:5078: result: dir1/generic
...
```

My environment produces (using `$HOME` for brevity)

```
LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/usr/local/lib:...
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/usr/local/lib:...
CPATH=$HOME/usr/local/include:...
PATH=$HOME/usr/local/bin:...
```

**How is it posible that the source directory of `tcl` was found?
I expected that `tcl` was found in `$HOME/usr/local`.
Perhaps `expect` is somehow reading the configuration of `tcl`, which looks very strange to me.**

Comment: is expect's src dir in the same dir as tcl's src dir?

Comment: @pynexj - No it is not. They are directories at the same level.

Comment: it's like `/some/dir/tcl-x.x/` and `/some/dir/expect-x.x/`, right?

Comment: @pynexj - That is correct.

Comment: It found Tcl in a sibling directory using a default search? What's the problem?

Comment: @DonalFellows - What do you mean by "default search"? What would the "default locations" to look for prerequisites be? I doubt it is in directories at the same level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `--with-tcl` is not specified it'll first try to see if there's also a Tcl's build dir in the same dir level (actually it'll also try 2 dir levels higher). For example, if you have

```
/src/dir/of/expect-5.xx
```

then it'll see if there's also

```
/src/dir/of/tcl-8.xx
# and 
/src/dir/of/tcl-8.xx/unix/tclConfig.sh
```

The Expect author may think people may first compile Tcl and then Expect at the same time. :)

See the file `tclconfig/tcl.m4` in Expect's source code, lines 80~105:

```
 63
 64  # First check to see if --with-tcl was specified.
 65  if test x"${with_tclconfig}" != x ; then
 66      case "${with_tclconfig}" in
 67          */tclConfig.sh )
 68              if test -f "${with_tclconfig}"; then
 69                  AC_MSG_WARN([--with-tcl argument should refer to directory containing tclConfig.sh, not to tclConfig.sh itself])
 70                  with_tclconfig="`echo "${with_tclconfig}" | sed 's!/tclConfig\.sh$!!'`"
 71              fi ;;
 72      esac
 73      if test -f "${with_tclconfig}/tclConfig.sh" ; then
 74          ac_cv_c_tclconfig="`(cd "${with_tclconfig}"; pwd)`"
 75      else
 76          AC_MSG_ERROR([${with_tclconfig} directory doesn't contain tclConfig.sh])
 77      fi
 78  fi
 79
 80  # then check for a private Tcl installation
 81  if test x"${ac_cv_c_tclconfig}" = x ; then
 82      for i in \
 83              ../tcl \
 84              `ls -dr ../tcl[[8-9]].[[0-9]].[[0-9]]* 2>/dev/null` \
 85              `ls -dr ../tcl[[8-9]].[[0-9]] 2>/dev/null` \
 86              `ls -dr ../tcl[[8-9]].[[0-9]]* 2>/dev/null` \
 87              ../../tcl \
 88              `ls -dr ../../tcl[[8-9]].[[0-9]].[[0-9]]* 2>/dev/null` \
 89              `ls -dr ../../tcl[[8-9]].[[0-9]] 2>/dev/null` \
 90              `ls -dr ../../tcl[[8-9]].[[0-9]]* 2>/dev/null` \
 91              ../../../tcl \
 92              `ls -dr ../../../tcl[[8-9]].[[0-9]].[[0-9]]* 2>/dev/null` \
 93              `ls -dr ../../../tcl[[8-9]].[[0-9]] 2>/dev/null` \
 94              `ls -dr ../../../tcl[[8-9]].[[0-9]]* 2>/dev/null` ; do
 95          if test "${TEA_PLATFORM}" = "windows" \
 96                  -a -f "$i/win/tclConfig.sh" ; then
 97              ac_cv_c_tclconfig="`(cd $i/win; pwd)`"
 98              break
 99          fi
100          if test -f "$i/unix/tclConfig.sh" ; then
101              ac_cv_c_tclconfig="`(cd $i/unix; pwd)`"
102              break
103          fi
104      done
105  fi
106
```

Comment: I understand you mean that: 1) lines 100-103 are likely responsible for 
`configure:2650: result: found dir1/unix/tclConfig.sh`
`configure:2656: checking for existence of dir1/unix/tclConfig.sh`
and, 2) other files found in `dir1` follow from similar lines. Is that correct? If so, it would be instructive if you add it to the answer.

Comment: not a native English speaker. a bit harder for me to explain such tricky things. did update my answer. plz take a look.